# How to create multiple file upload in magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: module, product-grid, magento2.4.3.p1, multiple-file-upload

I want to add multiple file upload option in the product edit form, and display it in the product grid in admin, and that uploaded files are display on the product details page in tab. can anyone have idea then please help me.

Comment: You can create multi file uploads,
1) Follow product gallery file uploads and create custom module and use same product gallery file uploader in your custom module.

Comment: thank you Zahid for your response